# C# Excel result comparation

Tags: c#

I have never learned this aspect of programming, but is there a way to get each separate result of a excel query(using OleDB) or the likes.

The only way I can think of doing this is to use the INTO keyword in the SQL statement, but this does not work for me (SELECT attribute INTO variable FROM table).

An example would be to use the select statement to retrieve the ID of Clients, and then compare these ID's to clientID's in a client ListArray, and if they match, then the clientTotal orders should be compared.

Could someone prove some reading material and/or some example code for this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: So do you want to filter the results through the query statement or just get a single field?

Comment: I want to be able to throw the fields that are fetched into an array for example and then compare the result with the ID's already in another array. Then which I need to start creating SQL update statments, which I can handle myself I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fetches rows from a sql procedure. Will probably work for you too with some 
modifications.

```
        using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectString))
        {
            Conn.Open();
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("THEPROCEDUREQUERY", Conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    // Find Id of column in query only once at start
                    var Col1IdOrd = reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");
                    var Col2IdOrd = reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");
                    // loop through all the rows
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // get data for each row
                        var Col1 = reader.GetInt32(ColIdOrd);
                        var Col2 = reader.GetDouble(Col2IdOrd);
                        // Do something with data from one row for both columns here
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
```